# How to find the argmax of a vector in PySpark ML

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

My model has output a DenseVector column, and I'd like to find the argmax. [This page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/DenseVector.html) suggests this function should be available, but I'm not sure what the syntax should be.

Is it `df.select("mycolumn").argmax()`?

Answer (score 2):

I could not find the documents for argmax operation in python. but you can do them by converting them to arrays

**For pyspark 3.0.0**

```
from pyspark.ml.functions import vector_to_array    
tst_arr = tst_df.withColumn("arr",vector_to_array(F.col('vector_column')))
tst_max=tst_arr.withColumn("max_value",F.array_max("arr"))
tst_max_exp = tst_max.select('*',F.posexplode("arr"))
tst_fin = tst_max_exp.where('col==max_value')
```

**For pyspark <3.0.0**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
@udf
def vect_argmax(row):
    row_arr = row.toArray()
    max_pos = np.argmax(row_arr)
    return(int(max_pos))
tst_fin = tst_df.withColumn("argmax",vect_argmax(F.col('probability')))
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to the second script you wrote - I just suspect that Scala/Java methods must be exposed somehow in Python but I don't know how exactly

Comment: Happy it worked. If this helped, consider accepting and upvoting the answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.select(col("mycolumn").argmax())
```